# Asp.net identity add drop down list to default register view

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, ado.net, asp.net-identity

I'm trying to learn add a drop down menu to the registration page using ASP.NET identity. I can get the drop down to show up when it's the only element in a view, but when I try to add it the the default 'Register' view, I'm getting an error:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Identity.Web.Models.Countries]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'Identity.Web.Models.RegisterViewModel'.

Here is what works by itself:

**Model:**

```
public class Countries
{
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string CountryAbbr { get; set; }
    //for drop down menu
    public SelectList CountryList { get; set; } 
}
```

**View**

```
@model DDL_Test3.Models.Countries
@{ViewBag.Title = "DropDown"}

@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Country,
new SelectList(ViewBag.CountryList, "CountryAbbr", "Country"), "--Select a Country --", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

**Controller:**

```
    public ActionResult DropDown()
    {
        List<Countries> model = SQLConnection.ddlGetAllCountries();
        ViewBag.CountryList = model;
        return View();
    }

    public static List<Countries> ddlGetAllCountries()
    {
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(SQLConnection.GetConnectionString()))
        {
            return connection.Query<Countries>("sp_GetAllCountries", commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure).ToList();
        }
    }
```

I guess what I'm confused about, is how do I get the drop down list added to the default 'RegisterViewModel', show below:

```
public class RegisterViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "UserName")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [EmailAddress]
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Select a Country")]
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string CountryAbbr { get; set; }
    //drop down list
    public System.Web.Mvc.SelectList CountryList { get; set; } 

}
```

**UPDATED**

Here is the missing controller:

```
    // GET: /Account/Register
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Register()
    {
        List<Countries> model = EntityData.ddlGetAllCountries();
        ViewBag.CountryList = model;

        return View(model);
    }
```

Here is the @RegisterViewModel view:

```
@model Identity.Web.Models.RegisterViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Register";
}

<h2>@ViewBag.Title.</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Register", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <h4>Create a new account.</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary("", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Country, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Country, new SelectList(ViewBag.CountryList, "CountryAbbr", "Country"), "--Select a Country --", new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Register" />
        </div>
    </div>
}

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Comment: The error is self explanatory - your passing the wrong model to the view. But you have not even shown the relevant code. No where have you shown the view which has `@model RegisterViewModel`, and no where have you shown the controller method that returns `List<Countries>`

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I added some missing elements to my original post. I understand the error, what I don't know is how to correctly add the drop down menu to the pre-existing `RegiserViewModel`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your GET method is passing a model of `List<Countries> model = EntityData.ddlGetAllCountries();` to a view which expects the model to be `@model Identity.Web.Models.RegisterViewModel`

Change your get method to

```
public ActionResult Register()
{
    var countries = EntityData.ddlGetAllCountries();
    RegisterViewModel model = new RegisterViewModel
    {
         CountryList = new SelectList(countries, "CountryAbbr", "Country")
    };
    return View(model);
}
```

and change the view to use

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Country, Model.CountryList, "--Select a Country --", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

There is no need to use `ViewBag` since you model already contains a property for the `SelectList`

Comment: Thank you @Stephen Muecke, that is exactly what was needed!